# How to decrypte a Lua file

Tags: unluac

I have a file that i think my old developer decrypted, So now i cant see

I tried using unluac.jar and i get the message
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The input file does not have the signature of a valid Lua file.

I also tried to decrypt it and got his message
error: too many arguments: main2_decrypted.lua

Im somewhat new to this kind of thing so any help would be greatly appreciated like i said im new to this kind of work and would be greatful if i could get his either decryted or decompiled so i can view this file